# How can I  save individual iterations of a parfor loop

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm struggling to save output of each PARFOR iteration, but until now without success. I've searched a lot online, and according to some official newgroup replies, the correct way to deal with saving in a PARFOR (i.e., addressing the "transparency" issue) is to use an external function in the following way (elementary example):

```
parfor i=1:120
  display(i);
  [LL ll] = eig(rand(1000,1000));
  record(:,i) = diag(ll);
  samplesave('save.mat',record(:,i),i);
end
```

along with

```
function samplesave(fname, data,i)
   persistent st;
   store(:,i)=data;
   save(fname);
end
```

the problem is that declaring "st" as PERSISTENT make the variable "persistent" *across calls* of the same worker, but not *across the PARFOR loop*, so that at any given point you have only the whole history of the last worker that managed to save; the next PARFOR iteration (from a different worker) will overwrite this record with the whole history of (only) that worker, and so on.

How can I incrementally save history of all the workers?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume there is a reason why you can't wait until after the loop terminate to save the entire matrix.

One idea would be to save each iteration independent of the others using something like this:

```
baseFile = ('part_%03d.mat');
parfor i=1:120
  display(i);
  [LL ll] = eig(rand(1000,1000));
  singleRecord = diag(ll);
  record(:,i) = singleRecord;
  save(sprintf(baseFile, i), 'singleRecord');
end
```

Then load the files one by one and combine the values into a single matrix.

```
mat = [];
baseFile = ('part_%03d.mat');
for i = 1:120
  d = load(sprintf(baseFile, i));
  mat(:,i) = d.singleRecord;
end
```

Comment: Thank you. The reason behind such a need is mostly preventing losses of data due to potential blackouts/software crashes, given that I need to run the script up to several days. A couple of (small) corrections is required in your example: 1) singleRecord is a non-classified variable in the ParToolbox jargon and cannot be used in this way, 2) in order to save, one still needs to call an external function. Overall, however, your idea is useful and actually circumvent the problem. The only drawback is that if the number or iterations is very high, one would end up with thousands of file.

Comment: @AndreaGiannuzzi I'm not sure what you mean about `singleRecord` being non-classified. I'm pretty sure its a temporary variable as its created inside the loop isn't accessible outside the loop. http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/brdqtjj-1.html#bq_of7_-5  If you find that you're getting overwhelmed with files you might consider making a temporary directory explicitly for saving the files.