# Iteratively appeding rows into a file inside a parfor loop

Tags: matlab

I have the following sample code:

```
clear;
v = zeros(100, 4);
parfor i=1:100
    disp(['iteration ' num2str(i)]);

    v(i,:) = [i i i i+rand(1)];

    temp = v(i,:);
    parsave( temp )

end
```

and here's the parsave code which appends the single rows of the matrix v into the test.dat file:

```
function parsave( single_row )
    dlmwrite('test.dat', single_row, '-append', 'delimiter', ',');
```

The problem is that the test.dat file is missing some of the rows AND columns:

...

40,40,40,40.92

6,6,6,6.8743

27

38,38,38,38.415

4,4,4,4.7561

...

As you can see the third row is missing three columns. This sort of makes sense in the parallel scheme. But how to fix this? One idea is to break the parfor loop into smaller loops (say 5 loops of length 20 rather than 100) and save batches of 20 rows outside of the parfor loop:

```
parfor i=1:20 %this is changed to 20 now

    disp(['iteration ' num2str(i)]);

    v(i,:) = [i i i i+rand(1)];

end

parsave( v(1:20,:) )
```

This works fine but it's not an optimum solution. I also saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132022/how-can-i-save-individual-iterations-of-a-parfor-loop) which suggests that I can save each row as a separate file and then combine them all into a single file (something like map-reduce). But I'm sure there has to be a better solution given that in my actual code my matrix is 60000 rows and I don't want to have 60000 single files saved separately. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Do not write to file on parallel code. No. Bad. No.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Can you elaborate a little bit more whenever you get a chance?

Comment: How would 2 people write in the same paper at the same time? and 64 people? They can't, there are "write conflicts". In the other question you linked, what the answerer does is give each person a different paper. Its the only way to make sure 2 people are not writing in the same place at the same time.

Comment: To add to that, writing to disk  is super slow, comparing to any other thing. And moving memory in and out parallel cores is also super slow. So you are losing all speed that you could have won with parallel computing because you are writing to disk. Its like having a high speed train stop every 10 km. You won't get there to the end faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing to a (binary) file, you are limited by your HDD/SSD write speed rather than by your processor speed. Therefore, it makes no sense to perform this task in parallel.

In addition, if you attempt to write something in a single file using parfor, you'll probably experience conflicts or race conditions, since two or more different processes will try to change the file at the same time.